# Inheritance with two functions with different signatures hides the non-virtual function

Tags: c++, inheritance

Forgive the obscure title. It's likely a duplicate but I couldn't find the correct phrase.

Consider the following inheritance hierarchy.

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void Foo(int i) { printf("A::Foo(int i)\n"); }
    void Foo(int a, int b) { Foo(a + b); }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    void Foo(int i) override { printf("B::Foo(int i)\n"); }
};

class C : public B
{
public:
    void Bar() { Foo(1, 2); } //error C2660: function does not take two arguments
};
```

`A` has two methods named `Foo` with a different number of parameters. Only one of them is virtual.
`B` overrides the virtual method.
`C` tries to call the non-virtual method and encounters an error.

Calling the method as `A::Foo(1, 2)` does work fine.

Question:
**Why can't the compiler deduce that the correct method is found on `A`?**

It seems odd we would have to explicitly add `A::` in a call such as:

```
C c;
c.A::Foo(1, 2);
```

Comment: You can add `using A::Foo;` in `B`, then the overloaded `Foo` is accessible without the awkward syntax.

Comment: @davidhigh Great workaround, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the member function named `Foo` is found at the class scope of `B`, and then name lookup stops, so the `Foo` in class `A` is not visible, and won't be considered for overload resolution, even if the version in class `A` is more appropriate. It is name hiding.

You can use `using` to introduce them into the same scope, and make overload resolution work as you expect. Such as:

```
class C : public B
{
    using A::Foo;
    using B::Foo;
public:
    void Bar() { Foo(1, 2); }
};
```

See [Unqualified name lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup)

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/IPXSR47891)

Comment: Yes, that is obviously the situation, but why? Does the standard mandate that name lookup stops at the first match, or would a more accommodating compiler be able to find the correct signature?

Comment: @Rotem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominance_%28C%2B%2B%29 <<< exactly your question. This is by design. It might be that a "more accomodating" compiler accepts it, just as there are compilers that accept void main. There is another word that describes such compilers: "incorrect". A good compiler is strict.

Comment: @Rotem This's defined behavior, so every compiler should do it in the same way.